# Ignore disallow install(user restriction) as device owner

Tags: android

I have device owner and system app capability for the app. Is there a way to restrict users from installing app (Using Device Policy [Disallow install](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager#DISALLOW_INSTALL_APPS)  user restriction) while installing packages?

Current code used to install (Taken from [TestDPC](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/afwsamples/testdpc/cosu/CosuUtils.java) sample code which is working)

```
public static boolean installPackage(Context context, InputStream in, String packageName)
        throws IOException {
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
    // set params
    int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
    PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
    OutputStream out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, c);
    }
    session.fsync(out);
    in.close();
    out.close();

    session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to allow or disable installation of apps :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if (allow)
                        dpm.clearUserRestriction(mDeviceAdmin, UserManager.DISALLOW_INSTALL_APPS);
                    else
                        dpm.addUserRestriction(mDeviceAdmin, UserManager.DISALLOW_INSTALL_APPS);
                }
```